# Quoted headers in FileHelpers

Tags: c#-4.0, filehelpers

I've been trying to get my headers to be quoted but unfortunately I can't figure out how.`[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]`

Only works for the data, not the header, and although I could just:

```
            UserSubEngine.HeaderText = '"WHATEVER,WHATEVER,WHATEVER"';
```

I don't want to write out the 23 different headers in one line.

I would rather use:

```
            UserSubEngine.HeaderText = UserSubEngine.GetFileHeader();
```

if at all possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`HeaderText` is the way to go. `FieldQuoted` does not affect the output of `GetFileHeader()`.

Here is the relevant part of the [source code](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/FileHelpers/Engines/EngineBase.cs).

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds a line with the name of the fields, for a delimited files it
/// uses the same delimiter, for a fixed length field it writes the
/// fields names separated with tabs
/// </summary>
/// <returns>field names structured for the heading of the file</returns>
public string GetFileHeader()
{
    var delimiter = "\t";

    if (RecordInfo.IsDelimited)
        delimiter = ((DelimitedRecordOptions) Options).Delimiter;

    var res = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < RecordInfo.Fields.Length; i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            res.Append(delimiter);

        var field = RecordInfo.Fields[i];
        res.Append(field.FieldCaption != null
            ? field.FieldCaption
            : field.FieldFriendlyName);
    }

    return res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: HeaderText is NOT what I want to use, that's ridiculously clunky and badly programmed that way, there has to be a better solution.

Comment: There is. It's a great opportunity for you to contribute [here](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers). Fix `GetFileHeader()` above and submit a pull request.